# C# - What's the best way to reduce the size of an image (for streaming over tcp)

Tags: c#, tcp, compression, screen, live

I've written an application that streams live screen to a remote app. It grabs the screen (resizes the image to 640x480) and then compresses the image using GIF compression (using `System.Drawing`), saves it into a `byte[]` array and transfers it to the other app.

The problem is that the image I get is about 50KB which means that at 30FPS it would require 1.5MB of data transferred each second. At the moment I only get 8-10 FPS. I know it's possible to solve this somehow. Maybe using the technique that flash videos use?

Comment: Any reason you are re-implementing VNC with a less optimized protocol ?

Comment: It's not about VNC, I'd like to transfer other types of video too. I need to know what's the best way to stream video at 30 fps.

Comment: see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_streaming_media_systems

Answer (score 2):

Personally I'd recommend using [VNCSharp](http://cdot.senecac.on.ca/projects/vncsharp/) - it will do most of the heavy lifting for you. Some might say that it'd be madness to code this up again.

If not then streaming images is a waste of bandwidth - you need to effectively build a video stream and transmit that.

Comment: Thanks, but I need something more customizable, so I could transmit other video data, webcam feed and movie clips.

Comment: VNC uses the RBF protocol which means Remote Frame Buffer; the library source is available and it would be easy enough to adapt to take alternative streams - it doesn't just have to be the desktop/screen. RBF was designed as a lightweight protocol for just this sort of thing.

Comment: I checked it out but it seems like it's only the client that's included in the source code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't need animation and want to stay with loss-less compression you would get somewhat better compression with PNG instead of GIF (and PNG is patent-free). [According to this](http://www.ou.edu/class/digitalmedia/articles/CompressionMethods_Gif_Jpeg_PNG.html) the savings is between 10 to 30%.

Answer (score 0):

I think use screen by screen capture isn´t a good approach to get a live screen streaming. Video formats, usually, assumes that between a lot of frames you have a small couple of areas that changes. In the other hand you´ll need to work a bit more to capture a video from the screen.

You can start from these articles:

http://betterlogic.com/roger/2010/07/list-of-available-directshow-screen-capture-filters/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/screencap.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Rather than compressing images, you'd better compress video streams. This is how video codec achieve high compression : by exploiting similarities into consecutives images in the stream.

If you compress your images one by one, you loose this performance advantage, and it makes a huge difference in bandwidth.

Comment: OK so what kind of video compression do you advise?

Comment: You need to transform your serie of images into a video stream, and that's the uncommon part. Once that's done, you can use for example AviFile, for which a C# wrapper is available here :
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx